# Is 98%+ purity Reagent Grade Ca-EDTA powder as safe to use as USP Grade in the body?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, safety, organometallic-compounds

Is $98\%+$ purity reagent grade $\ce{Ca}$-EDTA powder as safe to use as USP grade in the body?  Or, does the reagent grade have unsafe impurities that USP grade would not have even though they are the same purity?

Comment: Definitely not as safe. There's a much higher chance of lead and other common mineral impurities.

Comment: I wouldn't say it safe or unsafe but rather that it is risky.  The reason you shouldn't use reagent grade materials for internal use is because Reagent grade is based on purity alone.  USP grade is based somewhat on purity, but is more concerned with a lack of toxic impurities. your Calcium EDTA at 98% can be reagent grade but the balance 2% can be magnesium, sodium, nickel (though not likely), etc...

Answer (score 4):

*While normally health-related questions such as this one are considered off-topic, this one is sufficiently cut-and-dried that it probably merits an answer.*

***NO!!!!*** In general, reagent-grade chemicals are ***NOT*** safe to use internally like USP grades.  The entire point of the [USP](http://www.usp.org/) specifications is to ensure, to the extent practical, that the relevant chemicals are prepared from suitable starting materials and using suitable methods such that toxic or hazardous materials are absent from the final product. This is a big reason why the USP grades are often more expensive than the lab grades.

It's certainly possible that a given reagent-grade chemical may actually be safe to ingest, but there is no real way to know for sure without conducting extensive analysis of the impurities.

Comment: I'd agree that reagent grade shouldn't be used for ingestion. However I'd disagree about relative price. I think which is more expensive would depend on the chemical. I can buy table salt at the grocery much cheaper than reagent grade sodium chloride.

Comment: @MaxW Table salt isn't USP grade, it's food grade. (At least, I'm pretty sure there's a difference there.)

Comment: @MaxW $\ce{NaCl}$ isn't the best example... take instead BHT, the preservative. Sigma has [food grade](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/aldrich/w218405?lang=en&region=US) listed at US $274 per 10kg and [USP grade](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/usp/1082708?lang=en&region=US) listed at US $326.50 per 500mg.

Comment: @MaxW I'm pretty sure the key difference is that [food grades](http://www.usp.org/food-ingredients) are only approved for ingestion, while [USP grades](http://www.usp.org/about-usp) are approved for ingestion or inclusion in pharmaceutical formulations.